# Jasmine: Mocking Window['appdata']

Tags: angular, jasmine

writing some unit tests, I make use of the window obj. window['appdata'].something, to be exact. Was wondering how I would mock this for a unit test? as it is saying cannot read something of undefined.

I have tried with no avail:

```
    let windowMock: Window = <any> ['appdata'];

   { provide: 'window', useFactory: (() => { return windowMock; }) }
```

Comment: how do you use it in your app code?

Comment: Hey, simple use case -- just as below:

let locale = window['appdata'].apiUserlanguage;
let flow= window['appdata'].flow;

Comment: do you inject `window`?

Comment: nope, no @Inject(Window)

Comment: in the `beforeEach` simply add to the window `window['appdata'] = mockObject`. remove it in the after each `delete window['appdata']`

Comment: Did within the beforeEach

        window['appdata'].apiUserLanguage = "en";

and afterEach deleted, but getting error: 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'apiUserLanguage' of undefined

Comment: yeah, don't forget to clean in aftereach

Comment: clean? you mean delete window['appdata']? i've done so

Comment: yeah, right, cool